# Is an integer variable constant or logarithmic space?

Tags: asymptotics

My lecturer says that a variable takes up one memory position in RAM. This is the slide in question:

[image]

But CLRS (Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen, end of page 23) says an integer is represented by $c\ lg\ n$.

Are both statements true? How can that be?

Comment: Seems there are in view different things - can you, firstly, exactly point to page in CLRS?

Comment: @zkutch page 23

Comment: @Bee both your professor and the CLRS text is correct. Although others have written wonderfully nice answers, I felt like explaining in an alternate manner. See the term `memory position` used by your professor has no units specified explicitly, but intuitively by using the common meaning, it can thought as `memory word` which is actually measured in bits. In real world computers all the data types like `int, float, double` have a fixed data size and as such the bits required to store them are constant and taking this constant number of bits as a `memory position`, your professor explains.

Comment: @Bee, while CLRS being mostly a mathematics books and to make things more generalized, it does not assume any limits on the size of `n`. So it states that to store an integer of size `n` we need $\Theta(\lg n)$
no. of bits. Note the units, and the concept that here the size of the bits required to represent an integer is not bounded , rather it is allowed to be variable with respect to `n`

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh thanks for the explanation. I'm starting to understand now. If you don't mind, could you please explain why an integer requires lg n bits? I've read elsewhere that lg n equals the number of binary digits used to represent an integer. however, the integer 2 = lg 2 = 1, but in binary form, 2 is written as 10, which is two digits?

Comment: @Bee CLRS' language "each word can hold the value of n" is superficially confusing -- but "inputs of size n" and "enabling us to index the individual input elements" should make it clear the goal is to have enough bits to represent n different values -- if you want n=2 different values, well 1 bit (allowing "0" and "1") gives you two different values

Comment: @Bee when working with asymptotic notation, we check for order of growth and not exact actual answer. So let's work it out. Suppose we are given $x$ bits and using it we are to represent an integer $n$. Now the largest (unsigned) number that can be represented using $x$ bits is $2^x-1$ (why? Because we are given $x$ and the number of ways of filling this $x$ boxes using $0$s and $1$s is $2^x$. But binary counting starts from $0$ instead of $1$, so the $0$ to $2^x-1$ are assigned patterns here). Now for this $x$ bits to be able to represent $n$ we have, $2^x -1 \geq n $ or $x \geq \lg (n+1)$

Comment: @Bee So, $x = \lceil \lg (n+1) \rceil$

Comment: @Bee: In case Abhishek's explanation was unclear, perhaps this will help: Writing a base 10 number on a piece of paper requires Log_10(n) digits (i.e., you can store 10X more numbers by adding one more digit).  Writing a base 2 number requires Log_2(n) digits (i.e., you can store 2X more numbers by adding one more digit).

Comment: @Brian I appreciate your explanation. Its making things clearer. However, can you apply this using an example for me? Only because everything I've read elsewhere says a base 10 number (e.g. 7) requires lg 7 digits (which is base 2) but your comments says a base 10 digit requires log_10 digits. I'm confused about this mismatch

Comment: @Bee: In base 10, 57 requires Log_10 digits (i.e., two digits, namely 5 and 7 because `5*10^1+7*10^0 = 57`).  Log_10(57) = 1.75587485567, but we round up (this is not the same as ceiling: We round up even if it's an integer; Log_10(100) = 2 but we need 3 digits).  This shouldn't be surprising if you recall that Log_10(X) = Y can be rewritten as 10^Y = X.  The base 10 number 13 requires 4 binary digits (Log_2(13) = 3.7, which we round up to 4).  Specifically, it requires 1101 because `1*2^3+ 1*2^2+0*2^1+1*2^0 = 13`.

Comment: @Bee: The key is that if you want to talk about exact number of digits used, your logarithmic base will match your storage base.  Computers tend to store numbers in base 2 (i.e., binary), though you probably mostly read/write numbers in base 10 (i.e., decimal).  One final note of clarification: In Big O notation, the base of your log doesn't actually matter, since the change-of-base formula is just a constant multiplier, which Big O notation ignores.  So, you'll probably see inconsistent bases when people discuss this stuff in Big O context; this inconsistency is not an error.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transdichotomous_model

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [random-access machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_machine) is a common model of computation, which is the model of choice when analyzing algorithms. In this model, memory consists of words of length $\Theta(\log n)$ bits, where $n$ is the length of the input (in bits). Therefore both your lecturer and CLRS are right.

Comment: Note that it is important to understand what exactly your particular algorithm is doing - in many cases indeed using "values" of fixed width is fine. Analyzing complexity of general a^b or even a*b would generally require to explicitly represent values as sequence of "memory positions" (and than you find that limiting the input's width bring you back to "value fits into one memory element). Fortunately there are much more cases where all results have limited values (even most algorithms crypto has max "word" size for involved operations - thousands bits long but a fixed upper bound anyway).

Comment: Is the log base the size of the input, or the size of the memory?  I would think the latter would make more sense, especially since the basic primitive operations in the random-access model would be reading or writing a storage location by index, which would require an index that was capable of holding values up to n-1.  In some cases it may make sense to describe algorithms which use an indexable array of bits, but in most cases it makes sense to say that all storage locations are large enough to hold an index.

Comment: Usually we're interested in polynomial time algorithms, and then it doesn't matter whether $n$ is the size of the input or the amount of space used by the algorithm.

Answer (score 13):

In practical computer machines (aka, real-world computers) variables can be considered to be stored in "one" memory position, since the variable's size is fixed beforehand. For example, `int` is usually 32 bit long, and hence we can say it takes up "one" memory position of length 32 bits.

However, in the theoretical terms, integers do not have to be bounded between some arbitrary values we defined beforehand. That is, in the practical world integer with size 32 bit cannot store a value larger than $2^{32}-1$, but in the theoretical model it *can*. The caveat here, is that since we do not restrict the value of a variable, we need to actually consider how much memory it eats up. To save the number $n$ we need $\log(n)$ bits, hence what the book says is true, in the theoretical model.

Comment: If you need it for theory of computer science, then probably the $\log(n)$ is the way to think of it. Try thinking combinatorically, how many numbers can $k$ bits represent? if we say it does represent all the numbers between $0$ and $n$, then what is $k$ in relation to $n$?

Comment: But if we change the hardware & compiler a bit, we could have 64, 128, or I believe even 256 bit integers.  Perhaps even 512 bit: see Intel's AVX-512: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512

Comment: And there are practical examples of arbitrary-precision types which take much closer to $\log(n)$ space (such as Java's [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)), so it's not only a theoretical construct.

Comment: "variables can be considered to be stored in 'one' memory position" - except for strings in many languages, and integers in a few languages, and other classes/constructs that represent collections of other variables, unbounded numbers or other things. Unless by "the variable's size is fixed beforehand" you mean when the variable is created as opposed to all variables of that type being the exact same size, but from that it pretty much immediately follows that the entire computer memory is O(1), which would basically defeat the point of asymptotic analysis of code.

Comment: @BernhardBarker - that's the distinction between primitive types and well, everything else.

Comment: @Davor A class consisting only of a fixed number of fixed-size primitives would still be fixed-size, while what could arguably be called "primitives" in some languages are variable size (e.g. `int` in Python).

Comment: What's written here isn't always strictly true. Analysis of both theoretical algorithms and actual code sometimes ignore the fact that integers are technically O(log n) and just leave it at O(1) when the size of the value isn't significant enough to care about or won't change the overall complexity. This applies especially when we do something with the length of an array, string or whatever else represents our input as opposed to having the number itself be the input or output of the algorithm, and we similarly sometimes assume a number in a collection is O(1), yet theoretically unbounded.

Answer (score 3):

In mathematics, an integer can get arbitrarily big. However, the bigger a number, the more digits are needed to write it down.

A memory cell in a computer has finite capacity. Therefore, a single cell can only store integers up to a certain size.

A single variable, stored in a single memory cell, can therefore hold integers only up to a certain size. That's why most programming languages limit the size of their integral data types. For instance, in Java, a variable of type `int` can hold integers up to $2^{31}$ (about 2 billion).

That is, the word "integer" means something slightly different in mathematics and programming. CLRS was talking about the mathematical integers, while your professor was talking about the integral data types provided by a computer. The former may get arbitrarily big, and require many memory cells, while the latter fit within a cell by definition.

Comment: I'll note that there is some overlap.  "BigInteger" type classes supporting arbitrarily large numbers typically use O(logn) bits.

Answer (score 2):

**Integers take up logarithmic space** but this is usually of little interest during algorithmic analysis of real-world problems.

Here are things to keep in mind:

**1. Not the same $n$**

The $n$ often used in Big-O notation conventionally refers to the number of data items, rather than the possible range of those items. For example, if you are sorting 50000 integers and they are all smaller than 2 billion, that's $n=50000$ and $m=2000000000$. The input data will consume $O(n\,\text{log}\,m$) space. But often this will just be expressed as $O(n)$ because in the real world it's rarely important to consider mind-bogglingly-huge integers which is what it would take to make a serious difference here.

**2. Most algorithms are comparably affected by datum size**

One of the main reasons to perform asymptotic analysis is to compare two algorithms which solve the same problem. Most important classes of algorithm, such as sorting and searching and graph algorithms (e.g. shortest-path etc.) and optimisation algorithms, generally have the same asymptotic complexity whether they are operating on say 32 or 64 bits.

**3. There are exceptions**

If we consider things like very large prime number testing, the size of the primes can be crucial to accurately characterise an algorithm's behaviour.

Also, in abstract or theoretical environments it is necessary to be more rigorous about such things. Turing Machines typically have a fairly small alphabet (i.e. "variables" can hold a quite small range of values) so it is impossible to hand-wave away the size of an `int`.

**4. Many languages use variable-sized integers by default**

In Python, Ruby, Haskell and Raku, an integer is automatically allocated as much memory as it needs. You can multiply `999999999 * 999999999 * 999999999 * 999999999` in any of these languages and get a 100% precise result—they are not floating-point numbers. So if you create an array of really big integers you will see logarithmic memory usage. (CPU operations will also increase if the numbers are larger!)

**5. In practice, integer size (or numerical precision generally) is usually about machine selection, not algorithm selection.**

If you are trying to process 20-digit numbers on an 8-bit computer, you are using the wrong machine. You will experience a blowout of both RAM and CPU operations. The solution is not a change of algorithm but a change of hardware.

**6. Sparse integers can usually be collapsed with e.g. hashing**

Algorithms that require several copies of very large integers to be stored can be modified to save memory by hashing the datum or using indices/pointers. This step does not increase big-O performance complexity (although it does slow things down.) Figuring out the right trade-off to make is not really something that can be captured in a simple big-O formula.

Comment: Your example for point 4 can be shortened to `999999999**4` in the given languages (except Haskell, where `**` becomes `^`).

Answer (score 0):

A variable refers to exactly one memory position,  where "one memory position" is typically 64 bits on a modern computer.

When you want to store something bigger in a variable, you store a *reference* to the value in the original memory position.  This reference can be used to find a sequence of memory positions that contain the actual value.

These extra memory positions do *not* belong to the variable, but to the value stored.